# Split/separate rows in to columns by indent

Tags: r, excel

I have a large .csv file where the column variables are nested/indented rows:

[image]

- Company = ACME
- Client = Widgets LP
- Project = 2 - Home Security
- ..etc..

I want shape this file into tidy data by extracting the nested/indented variables and sticking them into columns like so:

[image]

NOTE: The indents are actually 5 spaces, (10 spaces, 15 spaces...)

**EDIT 1**: Please comment with constructive criticism

Comment: You may have to read the data with `readLines` and based on the number of whitespace in the beginning, create a grouping variable with `cumsum/grep` and split, but with just an image it is not easy to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have a reproducible example. Here's one to start:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c('a', ' b', '  c', ' d', 'e'), y = 1:5, stringsAsFactors=F)
df
    x y
1   a 1
2   b 2
3   c 3
4   d 4
5   e 5
```

It looks like a normal data frame, but the spaces are still there. I wrote a script to count the amount of spaces indented in the first column. Then it would add those counts to the data frame.

```
spaces <- gregexpr('\\s', df$x)
counts <- lapply(spaces, attr, which='match.length')
indx <- lapply(counts, function(x) length(x[x > 0]))
df$z <- indx
df
    x y z
1   a 1 0
2   b 2 1
3   c 3 2
4   d 4 1
5   e 5 0
```

If someone could figure out a way to 'go wide' on just the columns greater than zero while keeping the add columns grouped with the right rows, your problem would be solved.

From what I can tell, the intended output is:

```
newdf <- data.frame(x=c(rep('a', 4), 'e'), 
                    one= c(NA,'b', 'b', 'd',NA), 
                    two= c(NA, NA, 'c', NA, NA), y=1:5)
newdf
  x  one  two y
1 a <NA> <NA> 1
2 a    b <NA> 2
3 a    b    c 3
4 a    d <NA> 4
5 e <NA> <NA> 5
```